# wp-cli command throws error : "SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed" while querying https website

Tags: rest-api, wp-cli, ssl, https

I use `wp-cli` with [wp restful](https://github.com/wp-cli/restful) plugin installed.

Running `wp cli` command `wp rest user list --http=https://[url]` throws below error:

```
Error: Failed to get url '[url]': stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://[url]:443 (Unknown error).
```

The website is protected by self-signed certificate. How to cause wp-cli to work with website at `https://...`?

Is there `--insecure` or `--cacert` `curl` functionality in `wp-cli`?

Found [this](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/859) post, but found no solution there.

Comment: As another workaround you could add the self-signed certificate to the machine's CA store.

Comment: Or there's [a comment here](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/566#issuecomment-20195998) that you can edit in the -k, but I wouldn't know where.